# How to pass parcelable class through intent without null error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

ClassA:

```
public ClassA implements Parcelable {
    private ClassB classb; // Field
    ...

    // Constructor
    public ClassA(ClassB classb) {
        this.classb = classb;
    }

    public ClassB getClassB() { return classb; }
}
```

Class B:

```
public ClassB implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
ClassB classb = new ClassB();
ClassA classa = ClassA(classb);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("classa", classa);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

ItemListActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); // Receiving intent
ClassA classa = (ClassA) intent.getParcelableExtra("classa");
```

BUT, the problem is classa.getClassB() is returning null.
I'm not sure what the issue is, can someone help me out?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yeah no longer a fragment, I'm thinking it's more of an intent issue, or at least an issue with the startActivityForResult rather than just startActivity, but I have no idea :/

Comment: @a_local_nobody There are 7 String fields. I literally typed in "private String x" 7 times, implemented the default constructor, implemented the default getter+setters (By using alt+insert), and then typed in implements Parcelable, then did the prompted steps to implement it. That's it..

Comment: @a_local_nobody Interesting.. well thanks! this is really strange, I hope there's a simpler way than viewmodels but